# XPages application won't run

Tags: java, xpages

Our application runs fine on our own server (R9.0.1FP10). When we install it on another server (R9.0.1FP7), some pages function and some don't (Error 500). We can't figure out why or where they stop. The only difference is that our less complex pages seem to run, although there is one simple page that refuses to work.

Could it be the fact that the Extension Library isn't correctly installed? Does one have to install it separately on an FP7 server? Some rights issue maybe? Or what else could be the problem?

The error message in logreader.nsf shows this:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/minifier/ExtLibLoaderExtension.getOSGiBundle()Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;
 at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.minifier.ExtLibLoader.loadDojoResource(ExtLibLoader.java:149)
 at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.minifier.ExtLibLoader.loadDojoResource(ExtLibLoader.java:133)
 at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.minifier.ExtLibLoader.getDojoResource(ExtLibLoader.java:119)
 at com.ibm.xsp.minifier.ResourceFactory.getDojoResource(ResourceFactory.java:129)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRendererEx2.encodeOptimizedResources(ViewRootRendererEx2.java:501)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRendererEx2._encodeOptimizedResources(ViewRootRendererEx2.java:469)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRendererEx2.encodeResourcesList(ViewRootRendererEx2.java:449)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRenderer.encodeHtmlHead(ViewRootRenderer.java:647)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRenderer.encodeEndPage(ViewRootRenderer.java:519)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRenderer.encodeEnd(ViewRootRenderer.java:188)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRenderer.encodeEnd(ViewRootRenderer.java:179)
 at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
 at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.encodeEnd(UIViewRootEx.java:1374)
 at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:857)
 at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
 at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
 at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
 at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
 at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
 at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
 at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
 at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
 at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
```

Thanks all for your help!!

Comment: Any specific reason to skip the bug fix containing fix packs in production?

Comment: Not really, probably lack of time, and a heavily used Domino server. I'll urge them to move to FP10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of the Extension Library loaded on the FP7 server. I don't think any update was included in the base install until 9.0.1 FP8, in which case there could be differences. Maybe a module is included that's not available in the 9.0.1 core Ext Lib. I believe the OpenNTF version 901v00_17 corresponds to what was delivered with FP8.

Comment: Will check tomorrow, when we have access to the client's server. Thanks!!

Comment: Client was too busy to do either the upgrade or the install of the ExtLib. It's on for next Thursday...

Comment: There were remnants of R8 Extension Libraries on the server... After removing them and installing the FP7 ExtLib, the issue is resolved! Thanks! Still no FP10... it's on the wish list!